# Query Related to if conditional operator

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have got a method in which I have done something like:

```
int? products= formvalues["number"] == "" ? (int?)null : Convert.ToInt32(formvalues["number"]);
if(products.HasValue)
{ 
    // do some calulation
}
```

The Issue is I dont want to do calculation if product has 0 or null value else do calculation, How can I do that as the current logic avoid calculation when its null but it doesnt avoid when the product has 0 value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(products.HasValue && products !=0)
{ 
    // do some calculation
}
```

This works because `if` is using [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation): the `products!=0` condition is only evaluated if `product.HasValue` is true.

**Edit:**

This particular if statement also would work without short-circuit evaluation since `null!=0` - short-circuit evluation is useful if you have to access a member of a variable by prefixing it with a null check in the if statement.

Also as pointed out `Nullable<T>` provides the `GetValueOrDefault()` method to do the same check as above (@Bradley got my +1) - in this case it is a matter of personal preference /readability which to use.

Also the **real** answer your question should be to use `Int32.TryParse()` instead of "manually" trying to validate the input.

Answer (score 5):

Using your original code, you could write:

```
if (products.GetValueOrDefault() != 0)
{
    // do some calulation
}
```

[`GetValueOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx) will return 0 if `products` is `null`.

However, I would probably write it as follow (to avoid a potential `FormatException` thrown by `Convert.ToInt32` failing to parse user-submitted data):

```
int products;
if (int.TryParse(formvalues["number"], out products) && products != 0)
{
    // do some calculation
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the nullable int and perform a safer conversion:

```cs
 int products;
 bool parsed = Int32.TryParse(formvalues["number"], out products);
 if (parsed && products != 0)
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (products.HasValue && products.Value != 0)
{
    // do some calulation
}
```

Comment: The Issue is I dont want to do calculation if product has 0 or null value else do calculation

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this `if((products ?? 0) != 0){}`